# Set List Item Default to Edit Form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, jquery

We are using some Javascript customizations for SharePoint list items.  My boss does not like the fact that we have three forms to choose from (edit, new, and display) and wants the user to be able to click the list item Title link and go directly to the Edit form.  It is too much trouble (I guess) for the users to select what they want to do.

I found what I thought was a method located in https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/open-sharepoint-list-items-in-edit-mode-by-default.html but it didn't work.  I suspect likely because this is a classic page I am working with and this code is for the online version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  //Change display form links to edit form links
  $('.ms-vb a[href*="listform.aspx"]').each(function(){
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      url = url.replace("PageType=4", "PageType=6");
      $(this).attr('href', url);
  });
});
</script>
```

So, the question is this...is it possible to default a selected list item to open the Edit form and how might this be done?

Seems there might be a way to "route" to the Edit form but not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: The code is for Classic form.  You can *Return to classic SharePoint* in SharePoint online.

Comment: This is for SharePoint 2013 not SharePoint online...sorry for not specifying that.

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is happening if you add this code to your view page as described in the article?

Comment: I just tested in SharePoint 2013 and it worked perfectly for me (without changing a char)

Comment: I don't get any error.  Tried running the code in the console and what it seems in SP13 there is no .ms-vb selector as the object comes back with zero length.  Was trying to find out which selector to use instead of .ms-vb but was not able to find something.

Comment: When you say works perfectly do you mean when you select an item in a list it opens in Edit instead of display?  That is the intent here.

Comment: I think, your Jquery file **jquery.min.js** was not loaded in the console

Comment: it is because I can run other jquery methods.  I thought initially that was not the case but it's loaded.

Comment: No, double clicking the [Title] column as it contains the default link to the "display" form

Comment: You can manually load jquery file .. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console)

Comment: Then I would suggest editing the List View Page and add a script editor web part and try it that way.

Comment: The first method I tried was using a Script Editor web part loaded with the code above.  Received no errors but the page opened up in Display mode when I clicked the title link so the code basically did nothing.

Comment: Maybe there is something else is going on.. if you search for the class in the view source of the page, you should see the class exists.. **div class="ms-vb ..**

Comment: I'm a dummy...I was looking for the ms-vb class in the Display form after I clicked the title field to open the list item up and not in the list view page.  Going to try adding the script web part in the list view page and see what happens...that makes more sense.

Comment: Also, you can simply add an alert in the code to see if you get the message. If not, then there might be a syntax error in your code if you have modified it.

Comment: That was it!!!  I was not thinking about it right...it opened into Edit instead of Display when clicking the link.  Thanks for getting my head straight on this.  I was adding the code after the fact...adding it into a script editor on the display page. Thanks.

Comment: Good that it worked out.. hooray!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the original question works perfectly.  The issue I had was I had in my head to add the Script web part in the Display form which is after the Display form has opened when it really needs to be added to the List View so when the user clicks the Title url to open the page in Display Mode (the default mode) it get rerouted with the Jquery to open in Editor mode.

This also explains why when running the code in the console I was unable to find the selectors because I was looking in the Display form.  Doh!